# How facebook system works very fast

Tags: facebook, system

I am very curious about big social network platforms **fast working** system in software.Especially **Facebook**.

As instance,

If i block a user in facebook , i never see that user's messages,shares,images,etc etc.How facebook checks this if i block user or not in every image,share,post,message etc etc.

I also do not understand that , how facebook checks my friendlist friend's datas and bring me datas very fast in mainpage wall ?

I am not sure you understand what i want to tell you or not.But i want to know how facebook and big social platforms softwares are working very fast?

If you can help me i will be very happy.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Take some of these: [image]
2. Add a few billion dollars
3. Hire an army of witty nerds
4. Done!

Comment: All things done by servers ?

Comment: Fast servers, very efficient data housekeeping and infrastructure, combined with highly optimized code. These are the main ingredients, yes.